# find if key is in a multidimentional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i am creating a multidimentional array and i wish to know why the following code is not working and why the other with same value when im fetching the same array is actually working.

```
$fruits = array(
  "sale"=> array("banana", "apple", "orange"),
  "regular"=> array("grapes", "pear", "ananas")
);
```

then in the first case it return false

1st case :

```
$find_price = 'sale';
if(in_array($find_price, $fruits)){
   return true;
}
else {
   return false;
}
```

and in second example i got a result of true

```
$find_price = 'sale';
if(isset($fruit[$find_price])){
   return true;
}
else {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: `in_array` use for values not key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`in_array()` used to determine the **value** is in array or not. If you want to find if the **key** exist so `array_key_exists` is your friend

Look at the below snippet.

```
$find_price = 'sale';
if(array_key_exists($find_price, $fruits)){
   return true;
}
else {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: is that because it is a multidimentional array that "sale" and "regular" become keys  and not values ?

Comment: Yes. It is an associate array so `sale` is a key as like `0` is a key in simple array

Comment: thank you so if i understand i can use in_array('sale', $fruits) if the array was simple as $fruits = arra('sale', 'regular'); thank you very much i was wrong on my reading of php manual.

Comment: Yes if array is `$fruits = arra('sale', 'regular');`  but if array is `$fruits = arra('sale'=>'regular');` `sale` will be the key

Comment: thank you will set as correct answer in 3 min :D i cant now they say

Answer (score 1):

In your first code

```
$find_price = 'sale';
if(in_array($find_price, $fruits)){
   return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

You use `in_array()`. This `in_array()` function the elements into the array, That element exist in array or not. And you are finding a value which is key in the array. Instead of `in_array()` you can use `array_key_exists()`.

Your second code

```
$find_price = 'sale';
if(isset($fruit[$find_price])){
   return true;
}
else {
   return false;
}
```

You are using `isset()` this function tell that the element you find, is exist in code or not. Like you are finding `isset($fruit[$find_price])` means `isset($fruit['sale'])` that is exist....

Thats why this condition is true..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use loop for this type of conditions. try this.

```
 foreach($fruits as $key => $value)
    {

      if($fruits[$key]['sale']) 
      {
          return true;
      }
    else 
    {
    return false;
    }

    }
```